# Unit testing for POST request using Mockido error

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, jpa, mockito

The status I expect when testing is 200, but I get 404 instead right now.

I am fairly new to Mockido, so if there is something simple that I am missing.  Please let me know.

I have created a POST request in my controller that takes a List of Long objects.  If no exception happens, returns OK for status:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/postlist")
public ResponseEntity<Void> updateAllInList(@RequestBody List<Long> ids) {
    try {
        // method from ControllerService.java here using ids 
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(null);
    } catch (InvalidContentException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY).body(null);
    }
```

When I POST using a REST client, I am getting the correct results.  The raw payloads I POST are like this:

```
[
     2, 1
]
```

However, the unit test is giving me a 404.

The way I created the Test class is like this:

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @WebAppConfiguration
    @ContextHierarchy({ @ContextConfiguration(classes = RootConfiguration.class), @ContextConfiguration(classes = WebConfiguration.class) })
    @Category(UnitTest.class)
    public class ControllerTest {

         private static final String POST_REQUEST = "[ 2, 1 ]";

         @Autowired private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
         @Autowired private ControllerService controllerService;

         private MockMvc mockMvc;


         @Before
         public void setUp() throws Exception {

              this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.webApplicationContext).build();

              doNothing().when(this.controllerService).updateAllInList(anyList());
             doThrow(InvalidContentException.class).when(this.controllerService).updateAllInList(null);
        }

        @Test
        public void updateList() throws Exception {
            this.mockMvc.perform(post("http://testhost/api/configuration/postlist").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).content(POST_REQUEST))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk());
        }


        @Configuration
        static class RootConfiguration {


            @Bean
            public ControllerService ControllerService() {
                return Mockito.mock(ControllerService.class);
            }
        }


        @Configuration
        @EnableWebMvc
        static class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

             @Autowired
             private ControllerService controllerService;


             @Bean
             public Controller controller() {
                  return new Controller(controllerService);
             }
         }
    }
```

My theory is that in my test class I am plugging in the wrong content.  But why can't we plug in the same content as the one we use from real POST raw payload?

Thanks.

Comment: The POST_REQUEST string doesn't look like JSON to me?

Comment: @KarlNicholas Hi, if my raw payload when POSTing works in this format, is there something I'm missing that is causing the test to fail in this format?   I guess some extra characters are added automatically to the raw payload when posting, but what are they?  Thanks.

Comment: 404 is not found: is 'http://testhost/api/configuration/postlist` a real URL?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `MockMvc`, you want to trigger the mapping of your controller, not the HTTP server.

Instead of `mockMvc.perform(post("http://testhost/api/configuration/postlist")...`

Try `mockMvc.perform(post("/configuration/postlist")...`

Comment: Thanks for answering.  However, even after trying all combinations of my mapping, I am still getting a 404.  Do you think my content and my given (in the setup method) are correct?